# Getting past system alert on Android after device.openUrl call

Tags: detox

When I use device.openUrl I get the prompt to pick my app or the WebView Shell app (see image below).

Is there a way to set this up to always pick my app?

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you provide your app's package name, Activity definition in `AndroidManifest.xml` and the exact URL you're using in `openUrl()`?

Comment: Hi @d4vidi, apologies for the (LONG) delay. I think I have an idea of what's happening and it looks like it's by design looking at https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations and https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started. For the disambiguation dialog not to appear a Digital Asset Links file (served on the url in the intent) is required. Not sure if there's a way to bypass this requirement in a Detox test.

Comment: Did you manage to do so, ultimately? In any case, you might find this API useful: https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#devicegetuidevice-android-only